# How can I add an animation when an Item is added to a list in a v-for element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have this v-for iterating through the items in an "appFields" computed property.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between newAppField" v-for="(appField, index) in appFields">
                
                <input :id="'newFieldName-' + index" class="w-30 py-2 text-end" placeholder="New Field..." required type="texts" v-model="appField.Name">
                <select :id="'newFieldType-' + index" class="w-70 py-2 newAppFieldType" v-model="appField.Type">
                    <option v-for="typeOption in stateFieldTypes"> {{ typeOption }} </option>            
                </select>

</div>
<div id="addField"><fa icon="fa-solid fa-plus" @click="addField()"/></div>
```

Whenever I click on the "addField" icon, a new item is added to "appFields" and it appears instantly in my page.

The list of items is like this:

```
appFields: 
[
  {
     Name: '',
     Type: ''
  }
]
```

I would like to animate this item creation so it's not instant, something like a fade in, any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transition component. Check this out https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#the-transition-component